# An error-message pops up very short at startup and disappear. Where can I read it?

Tags: boot

Very easy for non computer/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS peasants, but I think the message provide some help,

Answer (score 1):

hardware-related messages are in `dmesg`, while others are in `/var/log/syslog`

```
dmesg | tail -n 50
cat /var/log/syslog | less
```